# Getting this error: argparse.ArgumentError: argument -d/--to-date: conflicting option string: -d

Tags: python, django

I am writing a Django management command. I would like to include optional arguments.

Within the Command class, I wrote:

```
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--from-date', type=str, help='Some help text')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--to-date', type=str, help='Some help text')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--from-type', type=str, help='Some help text')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--until-type', type=str, help='Some help text')
```

But whether I run the command with or without arguments, I get the following error:

```
argparse.ArgumentError: argument -d/--to-date: conflicting option string: -d
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You can't have the argument "-d" multiple times

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the same letter as a short argument. You should use something like below:

```
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--from-date', type=str, help='Some help text')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--to-date', type=str, help='Some help text')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--from-type', type=str, help='Some help text')
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--until-type', type=str, help='Some help text')
```